# How can I push a small change to heroku from my rails app without it taking 4 minutes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Every time I push to heroku, it is running bundle install and it takes me about 4 minutes. This is a small app that is not live yet. What if I only want to push a single change where I add one character to a view file? Is there anyway that I can tell heroku, here change this file and do it quickly without having to wait 4 minutes to run bundle install and everything else it does?

Comment: No however you could take a look at which gems are slow to bundle and find an alternative or just remove them while the site isnt live so you can test what is needed and then add them back for final deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait till Heroku auto deploy your project.

There is no way to tell heroku for minor changes, Its auto deployment process done by heroku so it will follow all steps like migration,bundle,pre -compilation.

And I think it's good for us.